# SQL Zend-framework update statement

Tags: sql, zend-framework, sql-update

What's wrong with this statement? An error is occurring, it is not reading the second line

```
(($var = array('tab.order' => 'tab.order+1');)) 

$db->update('tab', $form->getValues(), array('id =?' => $id));
                        $var = array('tab.order' => 'tab.order+1');
                        $var2 = array('tab.order >= ' . $form->getValue('order'));
                        $db->update('tab', $var, $var2);
```

Comment: What error is occurring?

Comment: no error it just doesn't do what i wanted to do which is updating all the rows in the order attribute

Comment: What do you mean by 'it is not readying the second line'? `$var` does not exist, does not have the value you expect, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely happening when `Zend_Db` does it's escaping of values in `$var`, and the value becomes

```
`tab.order+1`
```

You'll need to do

```
$var = array('tab.order' => new Zend_Db_Expr('tab.order + 1'));
```

to get around this.